# Shiny path to root folder?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have not installed a Shiny server and I would prefer that I did not. When I run runApp from RStudio I have a browser window opened at address localhost:port. I would like this application to read data from disk. At which path do I need to place this data in order for the client (index.html) to be able to do `window.open(path/data)` and a new window would open showing the raw data?

I have in **index.html**

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ("callbackHandler",
    function (value)
    {
        window.open(value.file);
    });
```

and in **server.R**

```
session$sendCustomMessage (type = "callbackHandler", message = list (file = trackfile, ...));
```

Comment: Normally you would place a `www` folder in the directory that `runApp` was ran from. This would then be your base directory from which files and folders would be accesible.

Comment: Well I had actually tried opening a new tab and entering http://127.0.0.1:8100/www/data.txt and I got back `Not Found` so I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `runApp` doesnt serve files. It listens on the given port and serves the one app on that port. Files can be accessed from the server side at `www` and made accessible to the ui etc.

Comment: If you want to have files served you will need to have a seperate http server running like python simplehttpserver or servr https://github.com/yihui/servr or the R rook package.

Comment: I guess you were right. Once I did `window.open("data.txt")` the browser opened the file. Post it as answer for the brownie points. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runApp` doesnt serve files. It listens on the given port and serves the one app on that port. Files can be accessed from the server side at www and made accessible to the ui etc.

If you want to have files served you will need to have a seperate http server running like python simplehttpserver or servr github.com/yihui/servr or the `R` `rook` package.

Comment: Your answer contradicts what the docs say?

If you got here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson2

Look for images, it says: 

"""
Your file must be in a folder named www in the same directory as the app.R script. Shiny treats this directory in a special way. Shiny will share any file placed here with your user’s web browser, which makes www a great place to put images, style sheets, and other things the browser will need to build the web components of your Shiny app.
"""